# Firebird does not forget default password after changing it for sysdba user

Tags: firebird

I am unable to make Firebird forget the old password for default user. I have installed Firebird version 3.0.4 on my local computer. I have tried to change the default password masterkey to another one via gsec tool. First I have logged in into this tool with command:

`gsec -user sysdba -password masterkey -database "C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_3_0\security3.fdb"`

And then with command modify I have set next password:

`modify sysdba -pw qwerty12`

The issue is that now I can login into sysdba account with both passwords, the old masterkey password and the new one qwerty12 password. How can I make the Firebird to forget the old default password?

Comment: Be aware, gsec was deprecated in Firebird 3 (because it will only use the first user manager configured). Since Firebird 3, it is recommend to handle user management using the [SQL user management statements](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#rnfb30-access-sql).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not that Firebird remembers the default password, the problem is that Firebird stores a password per authentication plugin, and SYSDBA happens to exist for two (or possibly more) authentication plugins.

To fix this, you must either drop the SYSDBA account for one of the authentication plugins, or change its password. Dropping the SYSDBA account is, unfortunately, rather hard to do for the Legacy_Auth plugin (you need to manually delete it from the security database, see at the end of this answer).

Assuming the standard Firebird install (which has authentication plugins Srp and Legacy_Auth), you need to do the following to change the password (note: I'm assuming that the problematic account is the one for Legacy_Auth, not Srp):

1. In `firebird.conf`, setting `UserManager` ensure both user managers are listed:

   ```
   UserManager = Srp, Legacy_UserManager
   ```
2. Restart Firebird
3. Change the password for both plugins

   ```sql
   alter user SYSDBA password '<new password>' using plugin Srp;
   alter user SYSDBA password '<new password>' using plugin Legacy_UserManager;
   ```

   Keep in mind: the legacy authentication plugin truncates passwords at 8 characters.

If you want to prevent authentication using the Legacy_Auth plugin entirely, then edit the `firebird.conf` and remove `Legacy_Auth` from the `AuthServer` setting (also check `databases.conf` if the database has a custom configuration).

I have asked a question on the firebird-devel mailing list about the inability to drop the Legacy_Auth SYSDBA account. The answer I got was that historically it was impossible to delete the SYSDBA account in older Firebird versions, so the Legacy_UserManager plugin explicitly disallows deleting SYSDBA (while Srp allows it). The workaround is to connect directly to the security database, and delete the user manually from the `PLG$USERS` table (which contains the Legacy_Auth users, Srp users are in `PLG$SRP`):

```sql
delete from plg$users where plg$user_name = 'SYSDBA';
```

You can connect to the security database using `isql -user sysdba -password <yourpassword> security.db` (assuming the `security.db` alias is defined in `databases.conf`, otherwise use the full path to your `security3.fdb`).

A slightly more obscure alternative would be to define a mapping that maps an authentication as SYSDBA using Legacy_Auth to a different (unprivileged) user (eg GUEST):

```sql
create global mapping NO_LEGACY_SYSDBA 
  using plugin Legacy_Auth 
  from user sysdba to user guest;
```

To drop the SYSDBA account for the Srp plugin, you only need to execute (as admin):

```sql
drop user SYSDBA using plugin Srp;
```

Comment: Since LegacyAuth is intended to fully emulate Interbase/Firebird 1/Firebird 2 behavior i do not think dropping SYSDBA from it has more chances, than dropping SYSDBA from Firebird 2.5 codebase. To somewhat lessen the impact the `UserManager =` setting could better be made belong to databases.conf instead of global firebird.conf

Comment: @Arioch'The The `AuthServer` setting is more important than the `UserManager` setting in this case.